# dompdf image not showing in blade file laravel

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I keep getting this error, `Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded`, whenever I try to download my pdf and I have look around and most of the people said to change php.ini max_execution time. I have already done that but still getting the error. I change it at the folder xampp/php.ini, not sure if it is the correct one. I tried looking under my laravel project for php.ini but there is no such file there. Another thing that I tried was putting `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` at the top of my blade.php but still doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

test.blade.php

```
<?php ini_set('max_execution_time', 60); ?>
<div class="container">
@foreach($object as $test)
@if( $pdf == 0 )
  <a href="{{url('/pdfview')}}{{$test->id}}">Download PDF</a>
  @endif
@endforeach
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 60%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Designation</th>
    <th>
      @foreach($data3 as $currentUser)
      <img src="{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
      @endforeach
    </th>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
</div>
```

pdfDownloadController.php (will get undefined error when downloading pdf so did this)

```
   public function pdfview($id)
    {

        $object = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();
        $object1 = additional_info::where('user_id',$id)->get(); 
         $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
         $object4 = language::where('user_id',$id)->get();

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('test', compact('id','object','object1','data3','object4'), array('pdf' => true));
        return $pdf->download('test.pdf');
          return view('test', array('pdf' => false));
    }
```

testController: //show in test.blade.php

```
     public function getBiodata($id){

          $object = personal_info::where('id',$id)->get();

        $object1 = additional_info::where('user_id',$id)->get(); 
         $data3=UserImage::where('user_id',$id)->get();
         $object4 = language::where('user_id',$id)->get();
          $pdf = PDF::loadView('biodata', compact('id','object','object1','data3','object4'), array('pdf' => 1));

     return view('biodata',compact('id','object','object1','data3','object4'),array('pdf' => 0 ));

 }
```

Comment: Most pdfs won't take more than a few seconds to generate (unless you have 10k+ pages ;p), check the code for infinite loops before fiddling with your server config.

Comment: you mean the part with forloop?

Comment: any loops, will need to see the code, to help further.

Comment: Sure hold on while I update the question

Comment: Updated @lawrenceCherone

Comment: You do have a few loops in there, which are not going to correctly structure the table. Can you explain how data3, object, object1, object4 are structured.

Comment: Are they all the same but you're duplicating them?

Comment: Updated question with explanation, what do you mean by duplicate? Which part?

Comment: Added answer (pink one) give it a try.

Comment: pink one? Just saw your post got deleted when i was looking at it

Comment: Yeah, i removed it (really an extended comment) refresh your page to see it. ;p. give it a try.

Comment: Tried it still loading, i don't think it work. I think i forgot something important to say inside my question, is that i am using php artisan serve instead of apache

Comment: The error appeared in the commond prompt this time after using your answer just now

Comment: Could this problem be because of the dompdf library that i used? I seen some people talking about it where it gave them the same problem @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Lots of people use that lib. but test it, bypass the PDF creation and just use the view as normal, see if it hangs.

Comment: The normal doesn't hang, it like it shows the normal view with the link to download the pdf but when i click the link it just timeout error

Comment: But you're not passing the data you're only passing `array('pdf'=>false)` try and get the table to render out as standard html, and then once working just add the PDF, if it hangs then it's the lib. https://3v4l.org/RgCVb

Comment: Im not sure you pass more then 2 params to view..

Comment: Wait what do you mean I am not passing the data? I did pass the data using compact

Comment: testController is to show the view page while the pdfDownload is for downloading the pdf

Comment: This is because for some reason when I click download they will give me an undefined error so I have to pass the data as well inside the pdfDownloadController that why you will see that this 2 controller are passing the same things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160913/discussion-between-dkna-and-lawrence-cherone).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i have done i one of my project :-
  Changed this:-

```
<img src="{{ url('images/' . $currentUser->name ) }}">
```

To:-

```
<img src="./images/{{$currentUser->name}} />
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is it like this <img src="./images/{{$currentUser->name}} /"> ? Or like this <img src="./images/{{$currentUser->name}} "/> ? Sorry was quite confused with the slash at the end

Comment: <img src="./images/{{$currentUser->name}} "/>

Comment: remove your img tag and add that i have suggested

Comment: Sorry need some time to go test it, i have deleted the code from last time so got to redo it again

Comment: @Dkna ok no issue you can test

Comment: yes it works, omg, thank you so much but just a question why in my blade, the image is not shown inside? it like those missing image over there kind. Sorry don't really know how to describe it

Comment: @Dkna  glad it helps you... i have also faced this problem few months back but i suggest you firstly you can google out to find the solution

Comment: @Dkna yes url  an asset function must work but i think pdf not support laravel url

Comment: Ohh I see so I guess just let it be for now, since the main function is already there hahaha

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working fine:

name ) }}">
or name ) }}">

Comment: can you clearly identify the section needing where to apply the change explicitly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).